Model Least Frequently Used cache algorithm with Markov chain
I am trying to model LFU cache operation using Markov chain. Users request contents that follow a known discrete distribution. The cache size is $n$ and there are $N$ number of contents. There are ${N \choose n}$ number of states with each state representing one combination of all possible set of contents in the cache. I am trying to create the transition matrix, P. I can't find the probability that a given object in the cache has the least frequent value. This is required because the LFU algorithm evicts the least frequently accessed content from the cache.
